# Graph colouring on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Color all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ one of $3$ colors, show there exist $2$ points of the same color of distance $1$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Problem:

(i) Show that no matter how we color all the points of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ in $3$ colors, there always exist two points at distance $1 $with the same color.

(ii) Is it true that for every positive integer k, when all the points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are $k$-colored, there always exist two points that are at distance $1$ and have the same color?

I am not sure how to approach the 1st problem, let alone the 2nd one. I'm sure this type of question are those kind of questions that require some insightful tricks

For part 2, I believe it is false, but I am unsure of how to prove that for any positive integer k, there will always exist 2 points that are at distance $1$ and have the same number

Comment: [Here are all your answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger–Nelson_problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) Assume we coloured the plane in such way that no two similarly coloured points are at distance $1$ from each other. Consider a triangle with each side = $1$. Its vertices A, B, C are distinct colours. Consider a point D symmetric to A with respect to BC. D must have the same colour as A.

It actually means that every two points at distance $\sqrt3$ from each other are the same colour. Then just consider a circumference of radius $\sqrt3$. All its points are the same colour as the center of the circumference. Obviously there are two points on this circumference at distance $1$ from each other.

(ii) Consider the regular tessellation of the plane with regular hexagons of diameter slightly less than $1$. Colour them with $7$ colours in a “chess” order, that is neighbour hexagons are of different colours. One can calculate the distance between the nearest same-coloured hexagons. It is greater than $1$.

Thus we get the counterexample for $k=7$.

You can consider the regular tessellation with squares of side $0.7$. Colour them with $9$ colours in such way:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
7 & 8 & 9 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

The diameter of every square is $0.7\cdot \sqrt2$ which is less than $1$. The distance between the nearest same-coloured squares is $1.4$ which is greater than $1$.